# Calculate the PDF and CDF of the normal distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function

I'm trying to manually calculate the PDF and the CDF of the normal distribution.

Starting from
$$N(x,\mu,\sigma) = e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

I know the next step is to say
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\partial x = 1$$

In my case, I can fix $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$, due to properties of my problem; meaning this simplifies to
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\partial x = 1$$

However, I don't exactly know how to follow up on this... I've tried one approach (described in the following), but I got a result that doesn't seem correct:

$$
u = \frac{-x^2}{2}
$$
$$
\partial u = -x ~ \partial x
$$
$$
\partial x = \frac{1}{-x} \partial u
$$
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\partial x = 1 = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{u} \frac{1}{-x}\partial u = \frac{1}{-x} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^u \partial u$$
$$= \frac{1}{-x} e^u = \color{red}{\frac{1}{-x} e^\frac{-x^2}{2}}$$

According to Wikipedia and others, I should get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} e^\frac{-x^2}{2}$$

Could anyone give me directions to where I should look for resources that can teach me what I am missing?

Comment: The usual method for calculating $A=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$ is to set up $A^2$ and convert to polar coordinates.  You get $A^2=2\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just take out the "$-\frac{1}{x}$" term from the integral, since you defined it as a function of $u$ when substituting $u=-\frac{x^2}{2}$.

Your question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502313/what-is-the-integral-of-e-x2-2-over-mathbbr).