# How do I integrate the integral for the independent Poisson random variable?

Tags: probability, integration

[image]

I don't know how to derive this (my red pen mark)

Comment: Have you tried expanding the integrand in Taylor series?

Comment: Do you mean take the derivative by derive, or solve the integral? I am a bit confused... To solve the integral, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502313/what-is-the-integral-of-e-x2-2-over-mathbbr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible explanation:

Since $\left| -\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \right | \approx 0,$ the interval of integration is very close to zero, and so $x^2 \approx 0 \implies e^{-x^2/2} \approx 1$.

Comment: $+1$. Nice.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Appreciations. @FelixMarin

Answer (score -1):

When $x \approx 0$, we have $e^{-x^2/2} \approx 1$. Since the text states that we are doing a slightly less than rigorous proof, replace $e^{x^2/2}$ with $1$ and the answer follows immediately.

Comment: This is literally the same as the accepted answer